# Using system.windows.forms on Mono develop on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, winforms, mono

I have been using ubuntu 10.04 and recently 11.10. I have mono develop installed thro synaptics or ubuntu software centre.

I have been doing c# and windows forms programming on visual studio on vista.

However, I have never succeeded in making system.drawing or system.windows.forms available in my mono develop on ubuntu.

The mono site advertises that system.windows.forms come installed with my mono installation. How can it be, I cannot find it? The mono site does not even have link for me to download the system.windows.forms libraries.

I need to get on with writing c# + winforms apps on linux, but which I will deploy on windows vista. Even though I have visual studio on my dual booted ubuntu/vista, I am a multi-threaded multi-tasking creature where I will perform both windows .NET and linux programming simultaneously. Therefore, I have to do my multitasking on ubuntu. No, do not suggest cygwin.

I cannot locate any system.windows.forms tools in mono develop on my ubuntu. All I can see is GTK# tools, and I am not interested in GTK. Please advise. Do I have to download windows forms libs for linux separately? Are there special steps which I have to make, which the ubuntu mono installation somehow failed to make, in order to have winforms tools available on mono develop?

[BTW, please refrain from politically charged questions/statements about why I am using windows technology on linux, vice versa]

Comment: I dont think you can use WinForms over linux, you have to GTK, even once i tried doing MessageBox.Show, it was not working, so i had to do it in a different way. So its not the same as you might think.

Comment: @zenwalker: I got winforms working on my Linux but I dont remember how. I remember it was really easy.

Comment: @zenwalker, WinForms library is available out of the box in Mono.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonoDevelop does not have a Windows Forms GUI designer, so you can't design your GUI using MonoDevelop. You should however be able to open your project in MonoDevelop and compile and run/debug it (you can also just copy over the binary from Windows and execute it on Linux).

If there is a specific problem that shows up when you try to execute your application please provide the error details (I think most distros include winforms my default and it should just work, but your distro might provide winforms as a separate package).

Have in mind that windows-specific p/invokes will likely fail, but fortunately there is a tool you can use to analyze your application to find many potential problems: http://mono-framework.com/MoMA